# Array bound set by a function of a generic

Tags: c++, g++, clang++

I want to set the array length to be the minimum of a constant and a generic like this:

```
template <int foo> struct Bar{
  void my_func( int const (&my_array)[std::min(5, foo)] ) { /*...*/ }
};
```

This code compiles with clang++ but not g++ and I need my code to work with both. The error g++ gives is: `error: array bound is not an integer constant before ']' token`. How I can set the length of this array to be the minimum of `foo` and 5?

When I use clang++ I run into the problem that I can't get anything to bind to `my_array`. I want to run something like:

```
int main() {
  static const int var[5] = {0,1,2,3,4};
  Bar<5> bar;
  bar.my_func(var);
}
```

But when I try to compile this code in clang++ I get: `error: reference to type 'const int [*]' could not bind to an lvalue of type 'const int [5]'`.

If I get rid of the `std::min()` stuff and replace it with `foo` the code compiles and runs fine.

**Notes:**
To get this code to compile you'll need to `#include <algorithm>` or similar to access `std::min`.

I don't think that this being part of a template should matter but when I try similar things with non-template function such as:

```
const int const_five = 5;
void new_func( int const (&my_array)[std::min(5,const_five)] ) { /*...*/ }
```

g++ says: `error: variable or field 'new_func' declared void` and clang++ says `candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'const int [5]' to 'const int [std::min(5, const_five)]' for 1st argument` which both look like similar problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it simple:

```
[foo < 5 ? foo : 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

For `int const (&my_array)[std::min(5, foo)]` to compile, you need a version of [`std::min`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min) which is `constexpr`. It is since C++14.

Check the default value for `-std` of gcc and clang you use (its version-dependant). Ultimately, compile with `-std=c++14`.

Provided by StoryTeller, a [nice working MCVE](https://godbolt.org/z/Q6MKkK).

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure which versions of C I'm using but I'm sure it's older than C++14, is there an easy way to find out? I'm looking around myself now. John Zwinck's answer works so I've accepted that.

Comment: Running `g++ --version` I can see that I'm on 4.9.4, which doesn't fully support C++14.